# Google Adsense - Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, adsense

I am using a google adsense ad unit inside an iframe, it was working fine until a few days ago when the ad stopped running only on chrome browser. it is working fine on Firefox browser.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://....." from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Any help would be much appreciated.