# Creating iframes with async scripts inside

Tags: javascript, iframe, asynchronous

I have a collection of scripts that generates iframes in a very simple fashion:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.densou-server.com/npm/sportensverden300x250.html");
iframe.width = '300';
iframe.height = '250';
iframe.frameBorder = 0;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

This used to work but it does not any longer. I host the script and embed it in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.densou-server.com/npm/sportensverden300x250.js"></script>
```

The console in Chrome reads out something like this:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.densou-server.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.domain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I cannot figure out why it is not working any longer. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: this can happen when a script *inside* the iframe tries to access the parent window, usually via

```
window.parent
```

Has the content loaded inside the iframe changed, do you know? I'm not talking about your code, but the code inside the `<iframe>` itself.

Comment: Good point. Thank you for the quick response. The content inside the iframe itself generates banners so that might be a possibility. The content inside the iframe itself is dynamically generated by Google AdSense. Assuming that this is the issue, how do we solve the problem?

Comment: Hmm. This could be tricky, if you don't have control over the iframed content. It looks like at least one other person has had the same problem recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533290/. I don't have an answer yet, but will investigate further...

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a definitive answer. This is a going to be a process of elimination. First, I would be inclined to check that your Google Ads have not been blocked. You should be able to contact Google tech support via your Adsense control panel, somewhere. Apparently it is a violation of their policy to embed their ads within iframes, and they may "take action against it". See here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3394713?hl=en#2. Please do post another comment when you've investigated that possibility - I'm interested :)

Comment: We will update everyone when we know someting. It cannot be blocking since this issue only exists in Chrome and Internet Explorer. Banners are showing just fine in Firefox.

Comment: Hmm. My next guess would be that it is a cross-origin request issue (the iframe content is served from a different domain than your website). But differing levels of security between your browsers is causing the error to appear in some browsers but not others. Other than that, I'm running out of ideas. Interesting one, this.

Comment: The tag is working again - maybe Google updated the AdSense script.